# Display all the distinct movie-genres and the average IMDb rating of each movie-genre in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a `movie` table inside my `Movie_Info` database which contains `Movie_Name`, `Movie_ID`, `IMDB_Rating` etc fields. Like this:

[image]

Now I need to **display all the `distinct` movie genres and the average `IMDb_rating` of each movie genre**.

I tried like this:

```
SELECT
        AVG (IMDB_Rating)
    FROM
        movie
    WHERE
        DISTINCT Genre
;
```

But it says error, maybe I can't use the `distinct` keyword with `where`. Please help me to write the proper SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to `GROUP BY` (aggregate) by genre:

```sql
SELECT Genre, AVG(IMDB_Rating) AS AVG_IMDB_Rating
FROM movie
GROUP BY Genre;
```